# Calculating NDVI values for specific zones using zonal statistics using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, ndvi, zonal-statistics

I am currently working with multispectral data from a MicaSense RedEdge M on a plot size study in wheat research plots. I want to conduct zonal statistics to calculate NDVI for individual plots.

I found a YouTube video from MicaSense entitled "Calculating zonal statistics for RedEdge-M data using QGIS" and the workflow helped me understand some things. However it did not go into detail on how to obtain the NDVI values. I have created an NDVI raster layer, by using the raster calculator and of course the formula for NDVI and respected bands. I created a grid layer, placed the polygons over the desired area, and conducted zonal statistics for each polygon.

I do not understand the statistical output in the attribute table neither how to convert the data to an NDVI index. Do you have any information on that?

Comment: The RS&GIS plugin says it will calculate NDVI from raw satellite data.